# Closed subspace $M=(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$ in PRE hilbert spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Is it true that $M=(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$ if $M$ is a closed subspace of a PRE hilbert space (a space with a scalar product, but that is not complete)?

The proof of the analog fact for hilbert spaces uses the projection on the subspaces $M^{\perp}$ and $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$, but if the space is not complete that projection may not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not true. In the edit to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/53330) on mathoverflow there is a simple and explicit counterexample.

Consider the pre-hilbert space $H = \ell^2_{f}$ consisting of sequences of finite support in $\ell^2$. Let $x \in \ell^2$ be the sequence $x_{n} = 1/n$ and
$M = \{y \in H \mid \langle x,y\rangle = 0\}$. Then $M \subsetneqq H$ is closed and one can check that $M^{\perp\perp} = H$.

Comment: Why M is closed?@giovanna lamberti

Comment: @C.Ding Continuity of $\langle x, \cdot \rangle$