# Are there some non-complete inner product spaces in which the equality holds:$M^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\operatorname{span} M}?$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and  $M\subset X$. We know that the following is true:
$$(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=\overline{\operatorname{span} M}.$$
But  I want to know is it true if $X$ is an inner product space .
Can someone help me prove it or give a counterexample? Thank you in advance.

I have tried some examples such as $X=C[0,1] $ and $M=\{f\in C[0,1]:f \text{ is constant}\}$,but all of them show the positive answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Double orthogonal complement is equal to topological closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043940/double-orthogonal-complement-is-equal-to-topological-closure)

Comment: @GuyFsone: Since this Question is explicitly asking about the non-Hilbert (non-complete) inner product space, it seems a short-circuit to choose a duplicate target that is explicitly about Hilbert spaces.  Was this intentional?  The Answer here brought out an interesting subtlety about how the dual is defined, so I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score -1):

This identity holds in all inner product spaces. The usual proof uses Hahn-Banach and no completeness is needed.

Comment: Thank you! But I have found a counterexample here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859092/closed-subspace-m-m-perp-perp-in-pre-hilbert-spaces/859115#859115.@gerw

Comment: Oh, I see. It depends on the definition of $(\cdot)^\perp$. I am used to use $M^\perp := \{ x^* \in X^* : x^*(x) = 0 \forall x \in M\}$, which is different for the (maybe more common) $M^\perp := \{y \in X : (x,y) = 0 \forall x \in M\}$.

Comment: Sorry,I should add the definition.  But I'm also interested in the  situation that $M^\perp := \{ x^* \in X^* : x^*(x) = 0 \forall x \in M\}$.Do you mean prove like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135883/showing-m-perp-perp-overlinem   .What I don't understannd in the proof is why $x_0\in E$ , is it necessary to add E is a reflexive space(e.g. ,$E^{**}=E$)?

Comment: No, for $N \subset X^*$, you define $N$ to live in $X$, i.e. $N^\perp = \{x \in X : x^*(x) = 0 \forall x^* \in N\}$. (So actually you have two definitions of $(\cdot)^\perp$ in order to work with the dual pairing $(X, X^*)$)